# UIImagePickerController move view lower

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I know the camera is 3:4 so there will be a black gap at the bottom. 
Now I create a custom cameraOverlayView which has a NavigationBar at the top. So is that possible move the camera view lower that can fill the rest of the screen?

[image]